# Failing to run Python script from R because of module ImportErrors

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, praw, rpython

I am trying to call a python script from an R Shiny app. I have tried using the system() function, which enters into the file properly but immediately fails after attempting to import any modules.

> system('python /path/to/name_of_file.py')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "< string >", line 2, in < module >
>   ImportError: No module named praw

I have installed praw using pip install praw, but I still get this error (actually, I get this error with every module that I have installed except for sys). The python script also runs fine from the command line. Does anyone know what I can do to properly integrate my R and python scripts?

Comment: maybe you have two pythons and you install modules in one python and run other in system() (every python has own folder with modules). Try to use full path to python in system()

Comment: I suspect you have multiple python installations on your machine, (2.7 and some 3.x, for example) and that pip is installing to one while R is calling another.

Try:

    sudo pip3 install praw

Or better yet, run the following python script from R:

    import sys
    print(sys.path)

This will give you an idea of which python R is using.

Comment: Try calling `which python` and from within R, `system("which python")` and see if the paths match.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, the paths were different and I've set mine to use the anaconda version from R